# Use look up table to assign boolean to column values in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is in the Scala Spark environment.

I have a data frame that has a column `paths` with values in the format: `[page1,page2,page3,page4,page5]`

I also have a data frame that maps these pages to their `parent_page`:

Example:

| page | parent page |
| --- | --- |
| page1 | parent_page1 |
| page2 | parent_page2 |

Each page can only be associated with a single parent, but a parent can be associated with multiple pages.

First, I want to append a column for each parent page on the original data frame. Then I want to loop through the paths in each row, and for each page, populate its parent page column with a 1 or 0 depending on if that parent page has a child page in the path.

Example output:

| path | parent_1 | parent_2 | parent_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [page1,page2,page3] | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| [page1,page2,page4] | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Most of my programming experience is in R, but I need to keep this in the Scala frame work for collaboration purposes. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a left join then pivot the `parent_pages`:

```
val pathDF = Seq(
  (Array("page1", "page2", "page3")),
  (Array("page1", "page2", "page4"))
).toDF("path")

val pathParentDF = Seq(
  ("page1", "parent_1"),
  ("page2", "parent_2"),
  ("page3", "parent_3"),
  ("page4", "parent_4")
).toDF("page", "parent_page")


val result = pathDF
  .join(pathParentDF, array_contains(col("path"), col("page")), "left")
  .groupBy("path")
  .pivot("parent_page")
  .agg(first(lit(1)))

result.show(false)

//+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
//|path                 |parent_1|parent_2|parent_3|parent_4|
//+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
//|[page1, page2, page3]|1       |1       |1       |null    |
//|[page1, page2, page4]|1       |1       |null    |1       |
//+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```